# python program not exiting on exception using aiozmq

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I am using aiozmq for a simple RPC program. 
I have created a client and server. 
When the server is running, the client runs just fine. 
I have a timeout set in the client to raise an exception in the event of no server being reachable.

The client code is below. When I run it without the server running, I get an expected exception but the script doesn't actually return to the terminal. It still seems to be executing.

Could someone firstly explain how this is happening and secondly how to fix it?

```
import asyncio
from asyncio import TimeoutError
from aiozmq import rpc
import sys
import os
import signal
import threading
import sys
import traceback
#signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)


async def client():
    print("waiting for connection..")
    client = await rpc.connect_rpc(
        connect='tcp://127.0.0.1:5555',
        timeout=1
        )
    print("got client")

    for i in range(100):
        print("{}: calling simple_add".format(i))
        ret = await client.call.simple_add(1, 2)
        assert 3 == ret
    print("calling slow_add")
    ret = await client.call.slow_add(3, 5)
    assert 8 == ret

    client.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.set_debug(True)
    future = asyncio.ensure_future(client())
    try:
        loop.run_until_complete(future)
    except TimeoutError:
        print("Timeout occurred...")
        future.cancel()
        loop.stop()
        #loop.run_forever()
        main_thread = threading.currentThread()
        for t in threading.enumerate():
            if t is main_thread:
                print("skipping main_thread...")
                continue
            print("Thread is alive? {}".format({True:'yes',
                False:'no'}[t.is_alive()]))
            print("Waiting for thread...{}".format(t.getName()))
            t.join()

        print(sys._current_frames())
        traceback.print_stack()
        for thread_id, frame in sys._current_frames().items():
            name = thread_id
            for thread in threading.enumerate():
                if thread.ident == thread_id:
                    name = thread.name
            traceback.print_stack(frame)
        print("exiting..")
        sys.exit(1)
        #os._exit(1)
    print("eh?")
```

The result of running the above is below. Note again that the program was still running, I had to  to exit.

```
> python client.py
waiting for connection..
got client
0: calling simple_add
Timeout occurred...
skipping main_thread...
{24804: <frame object at 0x00000000027C3848>}
  File "client.py", line 54, in <module>
    traceback.print_stack()
  File "client.py", line 60, in <module>
    traceback.print_stack(frame)
exiting..
^C
```

I also tried sys.exit() which also didn't work:

```
try:
    loop.run_until_complete(future)
except:
    print("exiting..")
    sys.exit(1)
```

I can get the program to die, but only if I use os._exit(1). sys.exit() doesn't seem to cut it. I doesn't appear that there are any other threads preventing the interpreter from dying. (Unless I'm mistaken?) What else could be stopping the program from exiting?

Comment: I'm guessing your exception is happening inside your async coroutine, and it's not getting propagated.

Comment: @WayneWerner thanks for the response. I have edited the question to make the problem clearer. As you can see, the exception is getting thrown and caught. This leads me to think that there is another thread hanging around preventing the program from closing.

Comment: @GregoryKuhn I've been able to reproduce this issue, I think you should report it in [aio-libs/aiozmq](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiozmq/issues).

Comment: @Vincent I've raised it as an issue. See here: https://github.com/aio-libs/aiozmq/issues/72